# Create multiple arrows between items in displaymath

Tags: arrows

I want to draw a diagram with the following two implications:

NM-CCA1 =/=> NM-CCA2 
                 <=

But so far I do not know how to draw two arrows between the items. I can only draw one and I also cannot explicitly show that one implication does not hold. How would I go about this?

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{NM-CCA1 \ar@2{->}[r] & NM-CCA2 \ar@2{->}[l]}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: I don't think a solution is available with xymatrix. You could move the arrows around (using `<-.5ex>` and `<.5ex>` after the `[r]` and `[l]` respectivally), but you can't define the crossed arrow (=/=>) you wanted. Available styles are describe [here](http://www.math.wichita.edu/~pparker/personal/latex/xyguide)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It is recommended to post not only code snippets but always a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Such examples help us to understand the problem and to test our suggestions before posting an answer. So it would help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, with a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stacktype{L}
\textrm{NM--CCA1} 
\mathrel{\stackunder[.7\baselineskip]{\stackon[0pt]{\Longrightarrow}{/}}{\Longleftarrow}} 
\textrm{NM--CCA2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or maybe this, with a one-macro change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stacktype{L}
\textrm{NM--CCA1} 
\mathrel{\stackanchor[.7\baselineskip]{\stackon[0pt]{\Longrightarrow}{/}}{\Longleftarrow}} 
\textrm{NM--CCA2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and thurough answer =)